# Android+Admob: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value(etc...)

Tags: android, titanium, admob, appcelerator

**My previous question got closed by a moderator, so please read this: The other threads do not resolve the problem. I have read them and tried everything.**

I'm trying to get AdMob to work in my Android app. I'm making a new question because I already followed the advice of previous threads.

- I'm using Appcelerator Titanium.
- Android API is set to 4.0.3 in Run Configurations inside Titanium.
- I've set `<uses-sdk
  android:maxSdkVersion="15"
  android:minSdkVersion="15"
  android:targetSdkVersion="15" />`
- `<android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`
- I've ran a Clean on my project
- I've set `target=android-15` in both `default.properties` and `project.properties`

Getting this error:

`[ERROR] /Users/Path/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml:13: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').`

What am I doing wrong/What is causing this? Thank you.

Comment: Please post a few lines of code around your AndroidManifest.xml line 13

Comment: I may have missed it, but has the API level 16 SDK already been released? I can't seem to find it in my SDK Manager or in [the list on d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#intro). Perhaps you meant to write API level `15`, since that matches your Android 4.0.3 run configuration?

Comment: You're right, it's level 15. (Changing it to level 15 doesn't work either though)

Comment: Mike T: http://pastebin.com/jFw9DFjT

Comment: did you find any solution? I have the same problem on Phonegap

Comment: which version of the ti.admob module are you using? I just got this working the other day once using admob module 2.0 and setting api level to 15. For some reason the 2.0.1 version just would not cooperate

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and was able to solve by downloading the latest Admob SDK from google: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

After downloading, navigate to your project folder > modules > ti.admob > (version number) > lib. Remove the current .jar file and replace it with the one in the latest admob SDK.